# 2D Stack implementation, getting NullPointerException

Tags: java, stack

I try to implement a 2D Stack like this
 `private Stack<Char>[][] objectGrid = (Stack<Char>[][]) new Stack[width][height]`

However, when I try to push an element to my stack, I keep getting NullPointerException
`(objectGrid[x][y]).push(ch)`
I checked the debugger, and figured that objectGrid[x][y] appears as null, so I can't do push on it. Is the above initialization wrong, should I do a for loop to initialize the second dimension of my stack array?

Comment: You need to initialize the elements of the array(s) - all positions are null otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add initialize loop to your code, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        objectGrid[i][j] = new Stack<Char>();
    }
}
```